# How can i pass different classes in a java method

Tags: java, class, parsing, methods

I am having two classes which i want to pass in a method so that i can use them to set up an array adapter.

Below is my vehicle class

```
public class Car{
   
    private int yearModel;
    private String brand;
    private int priceModel;
    private int numberModel;

}
```

Then Below here is my

```
public class House{

  private int id;
  private double area;
  private String whenBuilt;
  
}
```

There is a method that i am calling and which i should pass any of the one classes, how can i be able to do this

Below is my method

```
private void setUpAdapter(Class class){

  ArrayAdapter<class> clientArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clientList);

}
```

In normal circumstances i would just set up the adapter using

```
ArrayAdapter<Car> clientArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
```

or

```
ArrayAdapter<House> clientArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
```

But what i would like to achieve should look something like this

```
House house = new House()
Car car = new Car()

if(condition == something){
 
  setUpAdapter(house);

}else if(condition == something{

 setUpAdapter(car);

}
```

Comment: What functionality do the two classes have in common that you want to exploit? Surely there's some common superinterface you can write. If you genuinely only want them to be *any* objects (which is unlikely), then you can just pass `Object`, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo am setting up a drop down menu/spinner, there is a drop down for car and drop down for house i would just like to use one method to set up both of them, the condition is sometimes the cars drop down will be hidden and the house drop down will be hidden, i also want to use one loader for all of them in case the list for car and house is being populated at the same time i dont want to have one loader to load up and finish then the second loader load up again

Comment: Currently, these two classes have nothing in common. Please read about the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @NomadMaker i have just used those classes to reduce the time i had used to ask the question the classes that am using have the same properties

Comment: @NomadMaker Would you say the same thing if the he was just creating a list copy method.  The LSP doesn't mean you can't do a common operation on different classes with the same method.

Comment: @WJS Yes, there are reasons for ignoring the LSP. However, I don't understand exactly what the OP wants to do. This is probably due to my lack of imagination. However, in my experience (since the first public beta of Java), I've used the LSP in my code before I ever heard it put into words.

Answer (score 2):

You have a classic requirement of method overloading

```
Class A {
    public setupMethod(Car car){
     //do something here
    }


     public setupMethod(House house){
         //do something different here
    }

}
```

In the class you are invoking this make a new object and invoke the calls.

```
main() {
  A a = new A(){
  a.setupMethod(carVariable);
  a.setupMethod(houseVariable);
}
```

Look at this page for more reference
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_overloading.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can always use generics to pass an instance of any class.

```
public <T> void doSomething(T val) {
   // now do something with val.
}
```

Of course, `T` may not be compatible with what you want to do.  So you can constrain `T` if appropriate by using a bound.

```
public <T extends SomeOtherClass> void doSomething(T val) {
   // now do something with val
}
```

In each of the above you could replace `void` with `T` if you need to return a type T.

Answer (score 0):

Trillion has a good point. If you may modify the Car and House class definitions, you may also want to consider using a common interface. For example:

```java
public interface ArrayAdaptable<T> {
    ArrayAdapter<T> getArrayAdapter();
}
...
public class Car extends ArrayAdaptable<Car>{
    private int yearModel;
    private String brand;
    private int priceModel;
    private int numberModel;

    @Override
    public ArrayAdapter<Car> getArrayAdapter() {
        return null; // replace here with actual logic
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this will work with your driver logic, so it is just an idea.